How to solve this trigonometric equation to get -Sqrt[3]?
Reduce[{Cos[40 Degree - a] + Cos[40 Degree + a] + Cos[80 Degree - a] ==
      0, tana == Tan[a]}, tana, {a}, Reals] // Simplify // Reduce

get the result:
tana == -Csc[40 °] - Tan[10 °]

How to solve this trigonometric equation for specific real-valued solutions?
The process of hand calculation for this problem is as follows:



What's the problem with the provided solution?

@azerbajdzan To obtain the result of
−Sqrt[3]

$Version

(* "14.0.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (December 13, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

Use FunctionExpand to convert the angles from Degree to radians
FullSimplify /@ (Reduce[{Cos[40  Degree - a] + Cos[40  Degree + a] + 
       Cos[80  Degree - a] == 0, tana == Tan[a]}, tana, {a}, Reals] // 
   FunctionExpand)

(* tana == -Sqrt[3] *)

Or
FullSimplify /@ 
 Reduce[{Cos[40  Degree - a] + Cos[40  Degree + a] + 
      Cos[80  Degree - a] == 0 // FunctionExpand, tana == Tan[a]}, 
  tana, {a}, Reals]

(* tana == -Sqrt[3] *)



RootApproximant

SolveValues[{Cos[40  Degree - a] + Cos[40  Degree + a] + 
     Cos[80  Degree - a] == 0, tana == Tan[a]}, tana, {a}, 
  Reals] // RootApproximant


{-Sqrt[3]}


result = 
 tana /. First@
   Solve[{Cos[40 Degree - a] + Cos[40 Degree + a] + 
       Cos[80 Degree - a] == 0, tana == Tan[a]}, tana, {a}, Reals]

FullSimplify@ TrigToExp@ result

(* Out: -Sqrt[3] *)


-Csc[40 Degree] - Tan[10 Degree] /. Degree -> Pi/180 // RootReduce


-Sqrt[3]


RootReduce[-Csc[40  Degree] - Tan[10  Degree] /. Degree -> Pi/180] is simpler.
